# How to reduce the file size of converted particles

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a voxelated object and split each cube as different objects that I can edit them individually. But while doing this, I want my file size as optimum as I can.

What I've done so far is that

-I created a voxelated object with using particle system.

-Converted the particles.

[image]
Now the particles are independent objects but the problem is the file size. It is too big like approximately 33 mb for 6000 little cubes. 
I am new at blender and I don't know if this size is normal or not. When I tried to import it into unity, the program crushes every time.

Is there another way I can follow?

Comment: Do you need the cubes on the insides? If not then you could remove these. Do you need a specific file format? Is it necessary that the cubes are independent objects or would you just like to have the shape look like voxels? Please be aware that Unity is not a voxel engine and that your approach produces models with a high poly count likely unsuitable for such a game engine when used extensively.

Comment: This is really a problem within Unity. You need to investigate how to do GPU instancing in Unity. 6000 separate objects equals 6000 render calls and thats too much. This is out of scope for this forum.